# Array Syntax Issues with object operator

Tags: php, arrays, object, syntax

```
$transaction->setFields(
    array(
    'first_name' => $_POST['x_first_name'],
    'last_name' => $_POST['x_last_name'],
    )

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_one (`first_name`, `last_name`) 
    VALUES ("$transaction->setFields['x_first_name']",'last_name')");
```

Having issues calling from this array, has to be syntax but i cannot find a good reference.

Comment: What is `$transaction->setFields`?  P.S. You're missing a `);`

Comment: Lets assume the arrays created correctly.. how would you call from it?

Comment: So `$transaction->setFields` *is* an array (not a function)?

Comment: It depends on the type of object transaction is. Is it possible you are looking for something like $transaction->getFields('x_first_name');? Also, you shouldn't use mysql_query as it is to be deprecated and if the $transaction->setFields() function is not sanitizing the input data you should really do so using something like mysql_escape_string() or bindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is missing a `);` and there is a trailing comma on the last element. Also, your quotes in the query are wrong. Try this:

```
$transaction -> setFields(array('first_name' => $_POST['x_first_name'], 'last_name' => $_POST['x_last_name']));
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_one (`first_name`, `last_name`) VALUES ('" . $transaction -> setFields['x_first_name'] . "','last_name')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Array or not, always use curly brackets when you're accessing a variable from inside of double quotes.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_one (`first_name`, `last_name`) 
VALUES ("{$array['x_first_name']}",'{$array['last_name']}')");
```

You can find more information if you can search for "Complex (curly) syntax" in this page: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

Would be good to see declaration of `$transaction`.  Maybe uses SPL Array/Iterator or something?  Assuming no other getters though maybe there is a `getFields()?`

```
$fields = $transaction->getFields();
```

Or just use the array you passed in the setter.  Either way something like this using `[]`...

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_one (`first_name`, `last_name`) 
VALUES ("{$fields['x_first_name']}",'last_name')");
```

Insert blurb on [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons) and mysql_* being depreciated...